# htaccess - domain redirect on subdir - subdir name missing

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I have a few domain names. I'd like to redirect all of them to the primary domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/target\.net\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

The subdirectory `.htaccess` is set for the purpose of virtual routing (handled in an `index.php` file), and it looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But the subdirectory name is not 'passed' in the redirect process. So for example:

*example.com/thedir/2020/x/y/z*
will redirect to:
*target.net/2020/x/y/z*

Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: Stop using dynamic configuration files, they add complexity, are notoriously error prone and really slow down the http server. Instead implement such rules where they belong: into the http server's host configuration.

Comment: @arkascha Do you mean that there is no specific easy solution to this question?

Comment: Using the real http server configuration _is_ easier than using multiple dynamic configuration files.

Comment: @arkascha Alright, but if still, this is the system that I have, and I'd like to make as little changes now as possible?

Comment: There is nothing in those rules that "swallow" folders from the path. The backslashes in the redirection to https to no make any sense, but that is not the issue here. Could it be that you have implemented that first rule (the redirection to https) _not_ in the http host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder, but already in  subfolder? That would explain what you describe. THings are unclear from your question. I suggest you add a folder/file hierarchy to your question.